# virtual thread, executors and executor hook methods

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, virtual-threads

I am trying to figure out how to work with [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444) yet still use [`ThreadPoolExecutor#beforeExecute`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#beforeExecute(java.lang.Thread,java.lang.Runnable)).

My older code simply extends `ThreadPoolExecutor`, but its constructor takes core/max pool size, a queue, which are stuff I assume you should not use or need in virtual threads.

Is there a way to enjoy the `beforeExecute` with virtual threads?

Comment: I guess not. You'd need to implement a custom executor to provide this if you want to decorate the run calls. However, I don't really see the point of that, the executor returned by `Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()` will *immediately* create a new virtual thread and run it when you submit something to that executor.

Comment: That also provides you with an alternative, simply decorate the returned executor and do the "before execute" stuff in the various submit/invoke methods.

Comment: thanks...

not the ideal solution but will work.
i wonder, even though pooling of virtual threads is an anti pattern, maybe applications  that are heavy on executors, one can benefit by polling virtual threads.
the reason I say that is: virtual threads are no silver bullet, if the code is buggy then virtual threads will not help - it will make the problem even harder to find. so maybe one could benefit from the resource saving of virtual threads while using regular executors (with virtual thread factories). just a thought

Comment: The main purpose of `beforeExecute` is to re-initialize `ThreadLocal` objects. That is a non-issue with virtual threads.

Answer (score 2):

You can abuse a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to create a new virtual thread per task without an actual pool, like

```java
public class PseudoThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    public PseudoThreadPoolExecutor() {
      super(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0L, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS,
            new SynchronousQueue<>(), Thread.ofVirtual().factory());
    }
  
    public PseudoThreadPoolExecutor(RejectedExecutionHandler handler) {
      super(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0L, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS,
            new SynchronousQueue<>(), Thread.ofVirtual().factory(), handler);
    }
  
    @Override
    protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
      System.out.println("PseudoThreadPoolExecutor.beforeExecute() "
                       + r + " on " + t);
    }
}
```

however, there is no need for such an approach when all you want, is to have a hook to be executed before each task:

```java
public static ExecutorService newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor(
    BiConsumer<Thread, Runnable> before) {

    ThreadFactory base = Thread.ofVirtual().factory();
    ThreadFactory withBefore = r -> base.newThread(() -> {
        before.accept(Thread.currentThread(), r);
        r.run();
    });
    return Executors.newThreadPerTaskExecutor(withBefore);
}
```

```java
ExecutorService es = newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor((t,r) ->
    System.out.println("VirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor.beforeExecute() "
                     + r + " on " + t));
```

Answer (score 0):

`ThreadPoolExecutor` is not suitable base class for virtual threads as their pooling is not recommended. You, however, could subclass from `AbstractExecutorService` , which has nothing to do with pooling, provides nice support for `Future`, `Callable`, and the kind, and is a base class for `ThreadPoolExecutor` you liked.

An implementation might look like this:

```
public class VirtualThreadExecutorService extends AbstractExecutorService {

    private class Worker implements Runnable {

        private final Runnable task;
        private final Thread thread;

        Worker(Runnable task) {
            this.task = task;
            this.thread = threadFactory.newThread(this);
        }

        public void run() {
            runWorker(this);
        }

    }

    private final ThreadFactory threadFactory = Thread.ofVirtual().factory();

    private void runWorker(Worker worker) {
        final Runnable task = worker.task;
        beforeExecute(worker.thread, task);
        try {
            task.run();
            afterExecute(task, null);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            afterExecute(task, ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        new Worker(command).thread.start();
    }

    protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
    }

    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
    }
    
    // other methods

    @Override
    public void shutdown() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public List<Runnable> shutdownNow() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isShutdown() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTerminated() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

As you might notice, the semantic of `beforeExecute` and `afterExecute` is the same as of  `ThreadPoolExecutor` (for example, they are executed on the Executor's thread), and even some class design ideas (`Worker`) have been stolen right from there.

Another good question is the unimplemented ("other") methods, they are mainly about shutting down and termination.
As virtual threads are supposed to be [short-lived, fast and lightweight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77750151/should-virtual-thread-die-fast), all these methods could be left unimplemented. But if, for some reason, you want to implement them, other subclasses of `AbstractExecutorService`, like `org.awaitility.core.SameThreadExecutorService` or `org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService` can serve as a model.